# Why I can't change color on before pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I created div element with mini caret, now div looks like tooltip, I have problem with changing color of caret on second div, I change background color but I want to change only of mini caret.

In CSS is what I tried to solve this problem.

Reference, in secong tooltip, class `walter1` is imported, because, I don't want to copy all codes from walter1 to walter2.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/hfgxzsnv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caret gets its color from the border not the background. You have to override this rule `border-left: 13px solid #b2d4dd;` from  `.walter1:before`

You have to change `border-color` not `background-color`

Use

```
.walter2:before {    
  border-left-color: #dddddd;      
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hfgxzsnv/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
.walter2:before {
  border-left-color: #dddddd;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfgxzsnv/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Took some time to tidy the code a bit, other than that its the same thing the others did. you just change the border colour;

```
.walter2:before {    
  border-left-color: #dddddd;      
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfgxzsnv/7/)

Comment: Sometimes the fastest gun wins..Nonetheless it is a right answer...+1